# Ionic SVG image slow on iOS

Tags: ios, svg, ionic-framework, zooming

I'm developing an iOS app using ionic, I used an svg image and svg-pan-zoom to zoom on it and move a round it.

Everything worked well on my browser but on my iPad the "map" was very very slow takes long time to respond to zoom or pan events!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am using  PhotoViewer.show() from Ionic Native and it is amazing.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/photo-viewer/